# Return selected JSON object from mongo find method

Tags: json, mongodb, mongodb-query

Here is the sample JSON

**Sample JSON:**

```
[
  {
    "_id": "123456789",
    "YEAR": "2019",
    "VERSION": "2019.Version",
    "QUESTION_GROUPS": [
      {
        "QUESTIONS": [
          {
            "QUESTION_NAME": "STATE_CODE",
            "QUESTION_VALUE": "MH"
          },
          {
            "QUESTION_NAME": "COUNTY_NAME",
            "QUESTION_VALUE": "IN"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "QUESTIONS": [
          {
            "QUESTION_NAME": "STATE_CODE",
            "QUESTION_VALUE": "UP"
          },
          {
            "QUESTION_NAME": "COUNTY_NAME",
            "QUESTION_VALUE": "IN"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Query that am using :

```
db.collection.find({},
{
  "QUESTION_GROUPS.QUESTIONS.QUESTION_NAME": "STATE_CODE"
})
```

My requirement is retrive all **QUESTION_VALUE** whose **QUESTION_NAME** is equals to **STATE_CODE**.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It is a bit unclear... Are you trying to get the "QUESTION_GROUPS.QUESTIONS.QUESTION_NAME" only?

Answer (score 0):

If I get you well, What you are trying to do is something like:

```
db.collection.find(
{
   "QUESTION_GROUPS.QUESTIONS.QUESTION_NAME": "STATE_CODE"
},
{
   "QUESTION_GROUPS.QUESTIONS.QUESTION_VALUE": 1
})
```

Attention: you will get ALL the "QUESTION_VALUE" for ANY document which has a QUESTION_GROUPS.QUESTIONS.QUESTION_NAME with that value.

Attention 2: You will get also the _Id. It is by default.

In case you would like to skip those issues, you may need to use Aggregations, and unwind the "QUESTION_GROUPS"-> "QUESTIONS". This way you can skip both the irrelevant results, and the _id field.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to unwind the arrays and grab only the question values back

Try this

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
  $unwind: "$QUESTION_GROUPS"
},
{
  $unwind: "$QUESTION_GROUPS.QUESTIONS"
},
{
  $match: {
    "QUESTION_GROUPS.QUESTIONS.QUESTION_NAME": "STATE_CODE"
  }
},
{
  $project: {
    "QUESTION_GROUPS.QUESTIONS.QUESTION_VALUE": 1
  }
}
])
```